# URL healthcheck script

Tags: rust, http

Task:
develop a CLI utility for HTTP Health check at a given URL.

The check is performed in a cycle with a specified interval. On each iteration of the HTTP GET activity on the given URL.
There are three options for the test result:

1. `OK(200)`, in case the request returned HTTP status code `200`.
2. `ERR({HTTP_CODE})` if the request returned an HTTP status code other than `200`.
3. `URL parsing error`, in case the second argument is not a valid HTTP URL. Then the application ends.

The utility takes two arguments:

1. Integer value of the interval in seconds.
2. The HTTP URL to be checked.

Example:

```
~$./program 2 http://example.com/
 
Checking 'http://example.com/'. Result: OK(200)
Checking 'http://example.com/'. Result: OK(200)
Checking 'http://example.com/'. Result: OK(200)
^C

~$./program 1 http://httpstat.us/500
 
Checking 'http://httpstat.us/500'. Result: ERR(500)
Checking 'http://httpstat.us/500'. Result: ERR(500)
^C
```

Could you please review my solution/ and suggest improvements.

My code:

```
use reqwest; // HTTP request
use clap::Parser; // CLI 
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use url::Url; // Check url format


#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author = "mascai", version = "1.0.0", about = "Check interval and URL to check", long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Check interval in seconds
    check_interval: u64,

    /// URL to check
    url: String
}


fn check_url(client: &reqwest::blocking::Client, url: &str) {
    let response = client.get(url).send();
    match response {
        Ok(data) => {
            match data.status() {
                reqwest::StatusCode::OK => println!("Checking '{url}'. Result: OK(200)"), // Example: http://yandex.ru  
                error_code => println!("Checking '{url}'. Result: ERR({})", error_code.as_u16()) // Example: http://httpbin.org/404
            }
            
        },
        Err(error_data) => { // Example: http://yfakeSite2134123412341.com
            let error_code: reqwest::StatusCode = error_data
                .status()
                .unwrap_or(reqwest::StatusCode::from_u16(500).unwrap());
            println!("Checking '{url}'. Result: ERR({})", error_code.as_u16());
        }
    };

    
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
    let url = Url::parse(&args.url).expect("URL parsing error"); // Panic in case of invalid

    let check_interval: u64 = args.check_interval;
    // println!("User innput: {check_interval} {url}");

    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    loop {
        check_url(&client, url.as_str());
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(check_interval));
    }
}
```

Comment: Should there also be a result for a URL that's unreachable?  That sounds like a possible occurrence.

Comment: As Toby noted, I too think that the error prerequisites are incomplete. What about TCP and DNS errors?

Comment: You can use the [humantime](https://docs.rs/humantime/) library to parse a user-provided duration, rather than requiring they specify exactly seconds. And if you _must_ stick with seconds include the expected unit in the variable name, e.g. `check_interval_seconds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## time span

```
    check_interval: u64,
```

Wow, that's a lot of time.
A `u16` is less than a day.
I was kind of expecting a `u32` interval timer,
where four billion is more than a century.
But `u64`?
That's dozens of times greater than
the current age of the universe.
Maybe it's a little bit of overkill.

---

## PR cleanup

```
    // println!("User innput: {check_interval} {url}");
```

Debugs are fine during development when you're trying to get things working.

Once you've decided "it is Done" and you're requesting review
for a merge-to-main, then it's time to prune out such commented code.
(Also, nit, typo for "input".)

---

## narrow type

```
fn check_url(client: &reqwest::blocking::Client, url: &str) {
```

Hmmm, `.get()` seems perfectly willing to accept an `Url`
instead of a string.
The docs and tutorials tend to express it in terms
of a string for convenience of exposition, but here
you happen to have an `Url` in hand already.
Using the more restrictive type here would have documentation value.
Plus, it avoids the need to repeatedly re-parse.

---

## other success codes

```
                reqwest::StatusCode::OK => println!("... OK(200)"),
```

It's not obvious to me that request code shall always be `200` here.
An [IMS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) query could yield `304` Not Modified, or
we could get `204` No Data,
likely others.
Recommend you stick to "OK" and call it a day.
Or report the actual numeric return code.

Consider including a UTC timestamp in each report.

Consider using `\r` CR to overwrite successive "boring" status reports,
perhaps reporting that there were "{N} successes" in a row.

Consider terminating the loop after K failures.

---

## panic?

Panic'ing doesn't seem like a *bad* approach, here.
But consider doing a more graceful handling of error and then exiting.

For example, if this code was used by a caller that
requested a fixed number of checks,
or spawned a thread for it,
then the two bits of code would not compose well.
We panic at top-level, but not within a library routine.
As written, you are constraining the adoption
of current and slightly modified versions of
your `check_url()` routine.

Comment: Thank you for the review
I know that 200 is not only success code, but according to the task: "There are three options for the test result"